# Manage server exceptions with ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts

Hello how do I handle an exception of the server with ajax - jquery?

I'm developing a web application with Java and the struts framework. In the project I managed exceptions using the global exceptions:

```
<Global-exceptions>
    <Exception key = "label.exception" type = "java.lang.Exception"
    handler = "exception.ExceptionHandler"
    path = "pages / errore.jsp" />
    </ Global-exceptions>
```

and I used a ajax function that calls a post on an action like this:

```
function find (cer, descr, urlToOpen, windowName, idapp) {
$ .ajax ({
type: "POST"
url: "home.do?method=find"
date: {calledfunction: windowName, idfind: find, description: descr, idapp: idapp, urlToOpen: urlToOpen}
success: function (data) {
var = newWindowName windowName.replace (/ [^ a-zA-Z0-9] / g, '');
window.open (urlToOpen, newWindowName);
alert ("Next");
},
error: function (thrownError) {
alert ("ERROR");
}
});
}
```

The problem is that my action throws an exception (I forced myself) but is never opened the error page. Conversely it runs whatever is inside
success.

Comment: Is this your actual javascript?  If so there are a few errors any of which could cause an exception - space after the first `$`; commas missing from after several properties; `date` should be `data`.

Comment: There will have been some problems in the copy and paste. In Eclipse I wrote it correctly. Thanks anyway for the warning

Answer (score 0):

You should have `<% response.setStatus(500); %>` in your `pages/errore.jsp` so that same error status code will get flow back to calling Ajax function. Here `$.ajax`'s underlying code will check status code. As the status code is `500` which is different than `200 OK`; the `error:` handler will get called instead of `success:`

Comment: Ok thank you. In this way I have an error and the alert is showed but.. why my page error.jsp isn't open?

Comment: In case of Ajax, you actually get the response in handler; success or error. By observing response you manually will have to take user to required page.

Comment: So the fact that I have managed exceptions with strust in this way (<global-exceptions> ........) has no effect on the error?